# How to put the following soapUI request into Karate?

Tags: karate

Media type: Multipart/form-data and value as query type

Refer to the attached file for more detail

[image]

Comment: I have added my comments for previous questions. Thanks

Comment: no. there should be a green "tick" mark you should click on. look at other questions or do a search please

Comment: sorry Peter, I clicked on the green 'tick' mark on my previous answered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to `multipart field`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#multipart-field

And if you have query params, use `param`. But it is hard to understand from just a screenshot.

If you are still stuck, please provide a cURL command (you can export from Postman, browser etc.) and we can figure this out.